# changing views inside recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have made an app in which i have to show available travelling classes present in indian trains....
[the expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQgfF.png) the image shows how the available classes must look...

Every train has different travelling classes available..
i have used six different textviews to show the available classes

now the problem is...once I scroll the available classes changes and becomes incorrect like this... [notice the first and second rows the available classes gets changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nFQh.png)

the rows are not getting updated correctly because the viewholder recycles the views...but how to correct that

here is the adaptercode

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

ClassType[] classTypes;
MyRecyclerAdapter.CustomViewHolder holder;
private List<Train> trainList;
private Context mContext;

public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Train> feedItemList) {
    this.trainList = feedItemList;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public MyRecyclerAdapter.CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
    return new CustomViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyRecyclerAdapter.CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    this.holder = holder;
    final Train train = trainList.get(position);

    holder.expandableLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (holder.imageView.getTag().toString().equals("down")) {
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.uparrow);
                holder.imageView.setTag("up");
            } else {
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.downarrow);
                holder.imageView.setTag("down");
            }
        }
    });

    holder.trainNumber.setText(train.getNumber());
    holder.trainName.setText(train.getName());
    holder.from.setText(train.getFrom().getCode());
    holder.to.setText(train.getTo().getCode());
    holder.srcTime.setText(train.getSrc_departure_time());
    holder.destTime.setText(train.getDest_arrival_time());
    classTypes = train.getClasses();

    for (ClassType classType : classTypes) {
        switch (classType.getClass_code()) {
            case "1A":
                if (!classType.getAvailable().equals("Y"))
                    holder.firstac.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case "2A":
                if (!classType.getAvailable().equals("Y"))
                    holder.secondac.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case "3A":
                if (!classType.getAvailable().equals("Y"))
                    holder.thirdac.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case "SL":
                if (!classType.getAvailable().equals("Y"))
                    holder.sleeper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case "2S":
                if (!classType.getAvailable().equals("Y"))
                    holder.secondseating.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case "CC":
                if (!classType.getAvailable().equals("Y"))
                    holder.chaircar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != trainList ? trainList.size() : 0);
}

public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected TextView trainNumber, trainName, from, srcTime, to, destTime, firstac, secondac, thirdac, sleeper, secondseating, chaircar;
    protected ExpandableLayout expandableLayout;
    protected ImageView imageView;
    protected LinearLayout availableClasses;

    public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.trainNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.trainNumber);
        this.expandableLayout = (ExpandableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.expand);
        this.trainName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.trainName);
        this.from = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.from);
        this.srcTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sourceTime);
        this.to = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.to);
        this.destTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.destTime);
        this.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.arrow);
        this.availableClasses = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.availableClasses);
        this.firstac = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.firstac);
        this.secondac = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.secondac);
        this.thirdac = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.thirdac);
        this.sleeper = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sleeper);
        this.secondseating = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.secondseating);
        this.chaircar = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.chaircar);
    }
}
```

}

please help

Comment: hiding a view won't create a lag, because i have done hiding views i never encountered that. hiding view and showing it back when needed is the best possible way. check what else you are doing wrong. because hiding and showing view should not cause lag.

Comment: +1 for HourGlass, this should not make lag, also you can make use of Tabs, each travelling classes in a tab, and there you can list all available trips, a plus for this is categorization, so if user want's to see only `Travel Class A` user will open the appropriate tab directly

Comment: yes you are correct...the lag was because of 

`@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
       return position;
}`

but after removing this the hiding is not performed properly...some rows get correct while other rows get incorrect... is it because of viewholder??
@Yazan@HourGlass

Comment: if you want to ask about this you have to post full code of your adapter or recyclerview and explain your problem, not just saying `not correct, or not working`

Comment: @Yazan i have updated the question..please have a look..waiting for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First:** you have some ambiguity for the reference `holder` start by removing the member class declaration of variable `holder`

`MyRecyclerAdapter.CustomViewHolder holder;`

You don't need this, this could create some mixing when working on the views, either by you or by the Adapter class. start by this and see what you get.

**Second:** your code related to visibility only *HIDE* the views, which will create the bug you have when a view got hid on some list item, then even if it should be Visible on other items, you are not doing this.

so you should first show all related views (reset), then execute the `if-else` and hide what should be hidden.

add this before the for loop starts

```
holder.firstac.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
holder.secondac.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
holder.thirdac.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
holder.sleeper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
holder.secondseating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
holder.chaircar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

for (ClassType classType : classTypes) {
:
:
```